# Run JavaScript method and return parameter

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, webview

I want to run JavaScript function on my android app,this is how i create the webview:

```
m_FullJSWebView = new WebView(m_VideoView.getContext());
m_FullJSWebView.loadData(htmltmp, "text/html", "UTF-8");
m_FullJSWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
m_FullJSWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(m_VideoView.getContext()), "MyAndroid");
m_FullJSWebView.loadUrl("javascript:getValue()");
```

This is the html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue(){
       //return value to Android 
       var val= 50;
       MyAndroid.receiveValueFromJs(val);
    }
    </script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body >
    <form name="ipForm" id="ipForm">
      UserName : <input type="text" name="userName">
      <button type="button" onclick="getValue();">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the `JavascriptInterface`:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }
        //add other interface methods to be called from JavaScript

        public void receiveValueFromJs(String str) {
            //do something useful with str
              Toast.makeText(mContext, "Received Value from JS: " + str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

After i run it on my device the `receiveValueFromJs` function won't called.Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: did you check that `For applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above, only public methods that are annotated with JavascriptInterface can be accessed from JavaScript.`

Comment: probably not relevant for now, but you'll have to annotate your method for the next releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

> Note that injected objects will not appear in JavaScript until the page is next (re)loaded.

Which means that you must change your methods order like that:

```
m_FullJSWebView = new WebView(m_VideoView.getContext());
m_FullJSWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(m_VideoView.getContext()), "MyAndroid");
m_FullJSWebView.loadData(htmltmp, "text/html", "UTF-8");
m_FullJSWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
m_FullJSWebView.loadUrl("javascript:getValue()");
```

### edit (2nd issue)

the `name` parameter in the `addJavascriptInterface` is name of the java object in the javascript. it is the object on which to call the methods from the javascript.

Therefore, your call should be:

```
m_FullJSWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyAndroid.getValue()");
```

Comment: I change to this and the `receiveValueFromJs` still won't called

Comment: It's still won't call the receiveValueFromJs function, there is any other way to run JS and return a value from it

Comment: probably because `JavaScript interacts with Java object on a private, background thread of this WebView.` means that you cannot show a Toast from there.

Comment: The receiveValueFromJs won't call at all,i put breakpoint there

Comment: what device are you running on (what version ?)

Comment: Galaxy 3 , Android version 4.1.2